# How to send encrypted email through sendgrid using tls and vb.net API post call?

Tags: vb.net, api, post, sendgrid, tls1.2

I created a console program on visual basic asp.net that sends a generated email through a post API call. I was successful in sending an email to any recipient email using a godaddy domain through sendgrid. On this domain godaddy, I set up a proofpoint encryption attachment that should create encrypted emails through a trigger of putting "[encrypt]" in the subject line. However, it did not trigger because for the encryption to be automatically attached to the email it has to pass through the office 365 server. Since I am using sendgrid according to the workflow it doesn't go through outlook whatsoever:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/email-flow/

I have been doing research and I see send sendgrid supports end-to-end encryption with TLS. However, I cannot find anywhere how to establish this encryption with sendgrid and visual basic API calls. This program is for a medical diagnostic company, who will be sending patient information via email, to maintain HIPPA compliance the emails must be encrypted in some way. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub SendEmail(PARAMETERS_FOR_AUTOMATING_EMAIL)
        Try

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

            Dim uri As String = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"
            Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri)
            Request.Method = "POST"
            Request.PreAuthenticate = True
            Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer API_KEY")
            Dim json_data As String = "{""personalizations"": [{""To"": [{""email"": ""TO_EMAIL""}]}],""from"": {""email"": ""FROM_EMAIL""},""subject"":""[Encrypt]This is a automated report"",""content"": [{""type"": ""text/html"",""value"": ""Hello!,<br>Please find attachment.""}], ""attachments"": [{""content"": ""File_translated_to_64_encoded"", ""type"": ""EXCEL_MIME"", ""filename"": ""FILE_NAME_FOR_ATTACHMENT""}]}}"

            Request.ContentType = "application/json"
            Dim json_bytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json_data)
            Request.ContentLength = json_bytes.Length


            Using requeststream = Request.GetRequestStream
                requeststream.Write(json_bytes, 0, json_bytes.Length)
            End Using

            Dim responsecontent As String = Nothing
            Using Response = DirectCast(Request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse),
                    responseStream = Response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
                    responsecontent = reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using


        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrLog(ex, currentLocID)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

If you guys have any ideas to give me a solution please share! thank you in advance.

Comment: Do sendgrid have any c# examples you can convert?

Comment: no they do not..

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v2-csharp-code-example/ cough